# Как в django выдать пользователю права на время?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Сейчас я в своем проекте вручную добавляю/удаляю право на просмотр записей у пользователей. Есть способ сделать так, чтобы при добавлении права пользователю указать время действия? То есть, выдать право на время, по истечению которого django сам это право изымет у пользователя.

[image: Право, которое я выдаю]

models.py:

```
class PremiumTime(models.Model):
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Пользователь')
   permission_id = models.ForeignKey(Permission, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Право')
   start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Premium куплен')
   end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Premium истекает')
```

admin.py:

```
class PremiumUsers(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('user_id', 'permission_id', 'start_datetime', 'end_datetime')
   list_display_links = ('user_id',)
```

Вид в админке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании записи в админке - право пользователю не выдается. Как сделать так, чтобы оно присваивалось пользователю?

Comment: Может, запускать таску в определённое время

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать M2M таблицу

```
class PermissionTime(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeginKey(User, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    permission_id = models.ForeginKey(Permission, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    start_datetime = models.DateTime()
    end_datetime = models.DateTime()
```

Comment: Создал. Через админку добавляю право пользователю, но джанго его не видит. Исправил главный пост.

Comment: А нельзя проверять  current_date и если она больше end_datetime менять запись в базе обычным SQL запросом ?

Comment: @AlexseyKr тебе не кажется нагрузка будет большая? Каждый раз при заходе юзера, будет проверятся допустим 1000 людей. Конечно можно проверять только того юзера, который вошел, но а если на сайте есть профиль, где отображаются права, ну ты понял.